# Replacing pattern only when it matches a whole word

Tags: sed

Lets say I try to replace in a like this

```
asdasdasdHit Hitasdasd Hit Hit
Hitasda Hit Hit asdaHit Hit Hit
Hit Hitasda Hit
...
...
```

Is there  a way to get every "clean" Hit replaced with OK?
I tried /g but then everything gets an OK 
With `s/\ Hit\ /OK/g` the Hit on the newline gets lost.

Answer (score 18):

Yes.

```
$ sed 's/\<Hit\>/OK/g' file
asdasdasdHit Hitasdasd OK OK
Hitasda OK OK asdaHit OK OK
OK Hitasda OK
...
...
```

The `\<` will match a zero-length word boundary at the beginning of a word, and `\>` will do the same at the end of a word.

The *zero-length-ness* of `\<` and `\>` means that they won't match any character in and of themselves, but forces the adjoining pattern to match on a word boundary.

A *word boundary* is a point in a string where an alphanumeric character is adjacent to a non-alphanumeric character, such as the point between `␣` (a space) and `H` and the point between `t` and `␣` (another space) in the string `␣Hit␣`, or the point between the `t` and the immediately following newline on all three 
lines in the example data.

With GNU `sed` you may use `\b` in place of `\<` and `\>` (though it also understands `\<` and `\>`):

```
$ sed 's/\bHit\b/OK/g' file
```

... but BSD `sed` doesn't understand `\b`.

Comment: For your last comment about BSD sed that does not understand `\b`, just change sed with `perl -pe` keeping all the rest command as it is and will work everywhere....

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Or keep using `\<` and `\>` and it will work in `sed` on both Linux and BSD...  Perl is a bit heavier to start and run.

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't think BSD said understands `\<` and `\>`. E.g., `echo "foobar" | sed "s/\<foobar\>/bazqux/g"` yields `foobar`.

Comment: @weberc2 What BSD system are you on? I'm able to use `\<` and `\>` with the native `sed` on OpenBSD. It seems to fail on macOS, so I'm assuming you're on macOS or FreeBSD, right?

Comment: @Kusalananda macOS. Womp womp.